# Can I still use virtualenv after installing Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv

I used to use virtualenv to create different project environments, same library (different versions). Recently, I installed Anaconda to do some Machine Learning. When I try to create a new environment using virtualenv I get this error:

```
 (venv) usr@KC-SCE:~/Desktop/bTree$ pip install nltk
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in /home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nltk) (1.11.0)
tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.1 has requirement bleach==1.5.0, but you'll have bleach 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.1 has requirement html5lib==0.9999999, but you'll have html5lib 1.0.1 which is incompatible.
tensorboard 1.8.0 has requirement bleach==1.5.0, but you'll have bleach 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
tensorboard 1.8.0 has requirement html5lib==0.9999999, but you'll have html5lib 1.0.1 which is incompatible.
jupyterlab 0.32.1 has requirement jupyterlab_launcher<0.11.0,>=0.10.0, but you'll have jupyterlab-launcher 0.11.0 which is incompatible.
```

What I do not understand is that why I am not able to download a library that already exists! I may need it in another version or else.

Comment: It is installing the `ntlk` packages,  some of them are already installed. The problem here is `ntlk` is installing later versions of `bleach`, `html5lib`, etc. but other packages that you already have like `tensorflow-tensorboard` are compatible with older versions of those. To cope with this, after installing `ntlk` you need to install those incompatible packages by explicitly mentioning the version you require

Comment: @DEEPAKSURANA Thank you for the nice explanation. But I do not think NLTK is installed outside Anaconda, because when I write `import nltk` it gives me an error that this library does not exist. The thing that I am not understanding is shouldn't the virtualenv take care of that ? Since I am installing nltk in a different environment! Thanks again!

Comment: I am not sure, but from the 'Requirement already satisfied...' lines, it doesn't seem like it is looking for packages in `venv`. In `venv`, you might want to check `sys.path`